# Why is DataReader and DataWriter class not found in Java like DataStreamReader and DataStreamWriter?

Tags: java, io

I am learning java io. But I found that DataReader and DataWriter class are not there in java like DataInputStream and DataOutputStream. Why?

I mean there are analogous class like FileInputStream and FileReader, then why not these?

Comment: What is your point?

Comment: A reader reads text. Suppose such a class exists, and allows reading integers using readInt(), for example. How would it read a file containing, for example, `123456`. Is it one int? two? three? How would it know? If you need structured information in a text file, use JSON, XML, CSV, or whatever other text ormat. Java is able to read any of those.

Comment: @JBNizet That was helpful

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. I searched both google and stackoverflow for this, couldn't find anything. At least give a reason for downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because they wouldn't make sense. Readers and Writers are for text and nothing else. Input and OutputStreams are for binary data, including all the things that `DataInput/OutputStream` provide such as `readInt()`, which reads a 4-byte binary integer in network byte order. You won't find that in a text file.